# Sql Server Profiler Unresponsive when showing long queries on single line

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-profiler

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am using NHibernate as DAL, and some mappings cause the generated queries to be quite long.

Because of that, when I try to view executed queries in sql server profiler, it becomes unresponsive, and after waiting 10-20 minutes!!! it will show the the query.

I need to mention that my PC has a SSD, i5 processor and 8gb of memory, so this is not a hardware problem.

Did any of you ran into this issue? Any fix for it?